# DUMP MySQL com base mto grande (BLOBs)

Tags: mysql, dump, mysqldump

Preciso fazer um *DUMP* de uma base gigante, ela possui mais de **500.000** arquivos PDFs carregados para dentro dela num campo *BLOB*.
É possível fazer um *DUMP* de uma base dessas e restaura-lo sem problemas?
Se sim, como fazer? Tem algum detalhe?

Tentei fazer do modo convencional: `mysqldump --user=root -p --host=localhost --result-file=arquivo.000 banco`, mas não funcionou, o arquivo gerado fica corrompido.

Hj está num servidor *Windows* e vou restaura-lo num servidor *Linux*.